# using setEditable method in if function

Tags: java

I have a TextField named `custDoe_TextField` and I have set the editability disabled as follows:

```
custDoe_TextField.setEditable(false);
```

Now I want to check if the editability is disabled or not and I planned to use `if` function as follows:

```
if (custDoe_TextField.setEditable == false)
{
   do something here
}
```

It is showing me an error, any tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isEditable()` instead. `setEditable` is a *setter* method, you can use it to set the *editable* property but not to retrieve it.

Also, use `!` instead of `== false` to check a boolean for`false`.

```
if(!custDoe_TextField.isEditable()) {
    // …
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java follows good naming convention for setters and getters for instance variables.
For eg. `int x;`
Setter - `public void setX(int valueToSet)`
Getter - `public int getX()`

For boolean values the convention modifies for getter to ensure good readability.
For eg. `boolean editable;`
Setter- `public void setEditable(boolean valueToSet)`
Getter- `public boolean isEditable()`

You need to use getter i.e., `isEditable()` to get the boolean property value of the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isEditable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html). for example

```
if (custDoe_TextField.isEditable()) {//isEditable returns boolean
    //do something here
}
```